# Switch case with cucumber steps and typescript

Tags: typescript, cucumber, webdriver-io

I use WebdriverIO6, Typescript 4 and cucumber.
I have this scenario:

```
Scenario: Login without password
And I enter valid email
But I do not enter password
Then I can see "Password is required" error message
```

And I have this step behind it:

```
Then(/^I can see (.*) error message$/, (type: string) => {
 const headerErrorMessage = loginPage.headerErrorMessage;
 const itemErrorMessage = loginPage.itemErrorMessage;

 switch (type) {
  case 'Authentication': {
   expect(headerErrorMessage.getText()).to.be.equal(errorMessages.headerErrorMessage);
   expect(itemErrorMessage.getText()).to.be.equal(errorMessages.authenticationFailedErrorMessage);
   break;
  }
  case 'Invalid email address': {
   expect(headerErrorMessage.getText()).to.be.equal(errorMessages.headerErrorMessage);
   expect(itemErrorMessage.getText()).to.be.equal(errorMessages.invalidEmailErrorMessage);
   break;
  }
  case 'Password is required': {
   expect(headerErrorMessage.getText()).to.be.equal(errorMessages.headerErrorMessage);
   expect(itemErrorMessage.getText()).to.be.equal(errorMessages.passwordRequiredErrorMessage);
   break;
  }
  default: {
  throw new TypeError('Unsupported type of error message');
  }
}
});
```

And the switch is not working. For that scenario it doesn't match `case 'Password is required'`. It just goes to default saying that it is `Unsupported type of error message`.
Does anybody have idea why?
Thanks!
**EDIT**
When I put this `Then(/^I can see "([^"]*)" error message$/, (type: string) => {` (notice I have `"([^"]*)"` instead of `(.*)`), then it works.
Can some good soul provide an explanation to this?
What is interpreted differently?
Thanks!

Comment: "([^"]*)" this means you are grabbing the text between the double quotes and in this case. Text from the feature file is getting matched.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what the regular expression does. But I don't get why switch is not working in case (.*) Since it also gets the text between the quotes...

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses are denoting a Cucumber capture pattern: (pattern).
The regular expression of .* is matching any character (except a newline) 0 or more
times.

Can you check the value of the 'type' argument during Runtime? You may be capturing "Password is required" **with** quotes from the Gherkin line which isn't matching your switch case.